# Backdate History Dates in Visual Sourcesafe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I would like to show some edits that were made to files and backdate the files in Visual SourceSafe to show the correct datetimes those changes were made.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you want to do that. But you may try this: check the file out, backdate your system date and check in back in.

I think it'd be easier just to add a comment on the history version though.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I might just comment.